# Bootstrap 3 table th fix width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I would like to ask , why not fix width th , and not make new line when the content too big? Now make expand the th width. How fix it ? My first column width: col-lg-2.

[enter link description here](http://kepfeltoltes.hu/150815/table_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png)

Comment: You should post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use columns in the head, the rest of the table will follow that pattern as far as size.

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>With Columns</h1>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr class="danger">
      <th class="col-lg-2">col-lg-2 - Row Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's. industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's.</th>
      <th class="col-lg-3">col-lg-3 - Row</th>
      <th class="col-lg-4">col-lg-4 - Row</th>
      <th class="col-lg-3">col-lg-3 - Row</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's. he printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been t</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's.</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's.</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's.</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's.</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's.</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's. Lorem Ipsum is simply
        dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<hr>
  <h1>Without Columns</h1>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr class="info">
      <th>Row fasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasd</th>
      <th>Row</th>
      <th>Row</th>
      <th>Row</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1.asdsadasdadasdad</td>
      <td>John.</td>
      <td>Carter.</td>
      <td>j@carter.com.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1.asdsadasdadasdad</td>
      <td>John.</td>
      <td>Carter.</td>
      <td>j@carter.com.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply with `<th width="7%">` e.g:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th width="7%">very very very very very long texttextextextextetxetxtetxtxtxtxtxtxtxt</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>mary@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>July</td>
      <td>Dooley</td>
      <td>july@example.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8mtu3oLr/embedded/result/)

http://jsfiddle.net/8mtu3oLr/